# AccuRev Visual Studio IDE Plugin 2016.1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, accurev

In my Visual Studio 2015, i'm using accurev visual studio IDE plugin 2016.1. Some of the accurev operations are not working properly.

1) Diff against operation throws error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz4UD.png)

2) Merge is always disabled.

3) In Web UI, when i compare with other version, there is no buttons/icons for "Revert their change" and "Restore my change" and there is no Merge button in version browser.

4) I couldnt see search operations like Pending, Modified, Kept, Non-member, default group, update preview, overlap, deep overlap, underlap, external, missing as in accurev.

Thanks,
Bharathraj.

Comment: Use the newer 2017.x plugin

Comment: I have installed 2017.1 plugin, still below things are not working,                            1) Web UI version browser is not working properly in VS2015 IDE but which is working fine in internet explorer and chrome.                                                                          2) Diff against most recent version, Diff against backed version, Diff against basis version and Diff against file on disk all are getting error like "Unable to perform diff operation"